# Error updating database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, payment-gateway

After submitting a payment form (credit cards, etc) to our payment gateway, we receive the "response_code" 1 when the payment is approved. We then use the following code to update a user's info in the database to reflect the approved transaction.

However, about every 1 out of 10 times, a user's info simply will not update even though the transaction returned an approved response. Is anything clearly wrong with this code? Or perhaps the response_code does not equal 1 for some reason?

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_GET['response_code'] == 1)
{ 
require('scripts/global.php'); //connect to database
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$level = 3;
$transaction_id = "" . htmlentities($_GET['transaction_id']);
mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET level = '$level', trans_id = '$transaction_id' WHERE `email` = '$email'"); //update user info
$error = "false";
}
else
{
$noerror = "true";
$message = "Sorry, an error occurred: " . htmlentities($_GET['response_reason_text']);
}
?>
```

Comment: What stops me from setting `?response_code=1`? Also, you might be open to SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because there has been a session timeout? The WHERE uses the e-mail address, if this is not valid (not there) then you probably won't get an update.

Maybe you should check for transaction ID (or similar). I guess you've got something like that before the transaction starts?

edit: Also store if an error occurs, and try to store variables you need too. This makes it a lot easier to pinpoint the problem. Use a logfile for this for example.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the obvious security holes, you're not checking the results of your query.  Try using [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) and [`mysql_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to see whether anything was updated.  When either indicates something unusual, you'll also want to see the exact text of the query that ran.  Things to check:

- Was `$email` empty?
- Did `$transaction_id` or `$email` have any apostrophes?
- Do you have duplicate email addresses in the database?
- Had the user already been set to level 3?
- Did you lose connection to the database?
- Did your script get called at all?